# Python time counter in Pygame-mouse events

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame, mouseevent

I want to calculate the time of user's mouse events in Pygame, if user doesn't move his mouse about 15 seconds, then I want to display a text to the screen. I tried `time` module for that, but it's not working.

```
import pygame,time

pygame.init()

#codes
...
...

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
text = font.render("Move your mouse!", True, red)

FPS = 30

while True:
    #codes
    ... 
    ...
    start = time.time()
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #catching mouse event 
    end = time.time()
    diff = end-start
    if 15 < diff:
        gameDisplay.blit(text,(10,500))

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Well output is not what I want, I don't know how to calculate it if user doesn't move his mouse.

> If I want to write a text when user's mouse in a special area, it's working like;

```
if 100 < cur[0] < 200 and 100 < cur[1] < 200:
        gameDisplay.blit(text,(10,500))
```

But how can I calculate? I even couldn't find how to tell Python, user's mouse is on the same coordinates or not.Then I can say, if mouse coordinates changes, start the timer, and if it's bigger than 15, print the text.

> **Edit:** You can assume it in normal Python without Pygame module, assume you have a function that catching the mouse events, then how to tell Python if coordinates of mouse doesn't change, start the timer, if the time is bigger than 15 seconds,print a text, then refresh the timer.

Comment: Your current code unconditionally sets `start = time.time()` at the top of the loop, so the `diff = end-start` calculated a little later will always be a relatively small number.

Answer (score 4):

To display a text on the screen if there is no mouse movement within the pygame window for 3 seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame

WHITE, RED = (255,255,255), (255,0,0)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
pygame.display.set_caption('Warn on no movement')

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
text = font.render("Move your mouse!", True, RED, WHITE)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
timer = pygame.time.get_ticks
timeout = 3000 # milliseconds
deadline = timer() + timeout
while True:
    now = timer()
    if pygame.mouse.get_rel() != (0, 0): # mouse moved within the pygame screen
        deadline = now + timeout # reset the deadline

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    if now > deadline: # no movement for too long
        screen.blit(text, (10, 50))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60) # set fps
```

Comment: I do not mind the downvote but I would appreciate an explanation. The code is tested and it does what its description says that answers the question as far as I understand.

Comment: Yes this is excatly what I want, can you give a good explanition about methods please then I can manipula it in my codes

Comment: @importV what specific methods do require more explanation beyond their documentation (have you tried to read it? Do you need help finding it?) and the existing  comments in the code?

Comment: @importV: the only relevant to your question variables are `timer`, `now`, `deadline` and `pygame.mouse.get_rel()`. Do you understand how they are used? The rest is unrelated to the current question but don't hesitate to ask a new question if something else (unrelated to timer) is unclear (the more specific question the better but provide more general context and link to this question).

Comment: Yes may I ask you explain them in your answer please?

Comment: @importV: ok. have you read `pygame.time.get_ticks()` documentation? do you know how to find it?

Comment: No, I see that method first time that's why I want an explanition.

Comment: @importV: I want you to learn how to find documentation for various `pygame` functions. It useful both in this case and in general. For example, what do you see if you search google for `pygame.time.get_ticks`? (the very first link is the link to the documentation for this function for me -- it might be different for you).

Comment: But usually documentations are confused me only, I prefer a little explanation from a user :) More casual, better^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68607/discussion-between-j-f-sebastian-and-importv).

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
start = time.time()
cur = None
```

before while loop.

You should also change `start = time.time()` in while loop to:

```
if cur != pygame.mouse.get_pos():
    start = time.time()
```

Also you could use `pygame.time` (it's similar to `time` but measure time in milliseconds)

Comment: I answered what you need to do if you want your program work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `while True:` code block is continuously running. The `cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` function is non blocking. This means it does not wait for mouse input - it will return straight away. So you need to initialize the `start` and `cur` variables *before* your `while True:` code block and then check the mouse position constantly in your loop.

If `cur` has changed since the last time the loop ran, then reset the `start` variable to the current time, and if the difference between the current time and `start` becomes larger than your 15 seconds, you can display the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that even without getting time, since you can calculate the pause as an integer counter through your FPS. Consider following example. Note that if the cursor is out of the window, the values of its positon will not change even if you move the cursor.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock( ) 
DISP = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

FPS = 25
Timeout = 15
Ticks = FPS*Timeout     # your pause but as an integer value
count = 0               # counter
MC  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
MC_old = MC

MainLoop = True
while MainLoop :
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.event.pump()
    Keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if Keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        MainLoop = False

    MC  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()        # get mouse position
    if (MC[0]-MC_old[0] == 0) and (MC[1]-MC_old[1] == 0) :
        count = count + 1
    else : count = 0
    if count > Ticks :
        print "What are you waiting for"
        count = 0
    MC_old = MC             # save mouse position

    pygame.display.flip( )

pygame.quit( )
```