# Python - try for a set period

Tags: python, time, try-catch, except

I Apologise for being a noob - both to asking questions, and python.
I've writen a program, which will be running full time. I have that working ok.  It uses the **try** function to look for an input from a touchscreen.

I now wish to **try** for 30s,and if there is no input, jump to a blackscreen routine (screensaver), from which it will be looking for any touch to go back to the original **try**

I think i need an **except** routine, but i'm tying myself up in knots working out with where to put everything.

Any guidance appreciated

### edit

this is Python for use on a raspberry PI.

all i have in code now, is the basic try as follows.

```
while(True):
    try:
        get_call()
    except SystemExit:
```

the **get_call()** routine, sets up some pygame screens, then looks to an **on_click()** routine for touchscreen input.

I wish to try to **get_call()** for 30s, and if nothing happens from that, go to **screensave()**

I know its not much to go on, my code is that of a self taught noob, with no knowledge of best practices, or decent formatting. If anyone wants to look through what i've done, i'll happily zip it all up, and send it through.

Comment: You should include your attempts so we can help you refine them.  As it stands, there are limitless ways you could approach something like you describe, making this quesiton too broad to be feasibly answered without knowing more about your application.

Comment: Could you share some code you have written for this problem?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @RobertB the mind reader :)

Comment: As everyone else said, we need some code, but there's something else. You're handling touch events with *exceptions*? That betrays some lower-level design problems.

Comment: what OS are you(and want to support) on is also information that is missing

Comment: Edit your original posting; comments aren't a good place for the example.

Comment: You could try `SIGALRM` in the `signal` module (see the example at the end of the [signal module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html). This should unblock the underlying blocking code and raise an exception. This can expose errors in the blocking code so test!

Comment: create a minimal but complete code example that does nothing but waits for a mouse click and call a function (`screensaver()`) if there is no click for too long. Here's a [related code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27885109/4279)